# using rocket chip(a library of chisel) to generate a axi4crossbar in verilog language

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip, axi4

I want to use rocket chip to generate a axi4crossbar with 2 slave ports and 1 master port, here is my chisel source code

```
package empty

import chipsalliance.rocketchip.config.{Config, Parameters}
import chisel3._
import chisel3.internal.sourceinfo.SourceInfo
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage
import chisel3.util.random.FibonacciLFSR
import freechips.rocketchip.diplomacy._

import freechips.rocketchip.amba.axi4._

object myAxiUtil{

val myAXI4MasterParameters = AXI4MasterParameters(name="Axi4Master", id=IdRange(0,3))
val myAXI4MasterPortParameters =Seq(AXI4MasterPortParameters(masters=Seq(myAXI4MasterParameters)))

val myAXI4SlaveParameters1 = AXI4SlaveParameters(
    address = Seq(AddressSet(0x80000000L, 0xffff)),
    supportsWrite= TransferSizes(64),
    supportsRead = TransferSizes(64)
    )
val myAXI4SlavePortParameters1 = Seq(AXI4SlavePortParameters(slaves=Seq(myAXI4SlaveParameters1), beatBytes=64))


val myAXI4SlaveParameters2 = AXI4SlaveParameters(
    address = Seq(AddressSet(0x90000000L, 0xffff)),
    supportsWrite = TransferSizes(64),
    supportsRead  = TransferSizes(64)
    )
val myAXI4SlavePortParameters2 = Seq(AXI4SlavePortParameters(slaves=Seq(myAXI4SlaveParameters2), beatBytes=64))

val myAXI4SlaveParameters3 = AXI4SlaveParameters(
    address = Seq(AddressSet(0x00000000L, 0xffffffff)),
    supportsWrite = TransferSizes(64),
    supportsRead  = TransferSizes(64)
    )
val myAXI4SlavePortParameters3 = Seq(AXI4SlavePortParameters(slaves=Seq(myAXI4SlaveParameters3), beatBytes=64))
}


//driver
class axi4Driver()(implicit valName:ValName, p:Parameters) extends LazyModule {
    import myAxiUtil._
    val node = AXI4MasterNode(myAXI4MasterPortParameters)

    lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp (this) {

    }
    override lazy val desiredName = "axi4Driver"
}

//accept
class axi4Accept()(implicit valName:ValName, p:Parameters) extends  LazyModule {
    import myAxiUtil._
    val node = AXI4SlaveNode(myAXI4SlavePortParameters3)
    lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp (this) {

    }
    override lazy val desiredName = "axi4Accept"
}

//top
class xbarTestHarness()(implicit valName:ValName, p:Parameters) extends LazyModule {
    import myAxiUtil._
    val numSlaves = 2
    //two axi4 drivers
    val drivers = Seq.fill(numSlaves){
        LazyModule(new axi4Driver())
    }
    //one axi4 accepter
    val accept = LazyModule(new axi4Accept())
    //axi4 interconnect
    val xbar = AXI4Xbar()

    //connection
    accept.node := xbar
    drivers.foreach {d => (xbar := d.node)}

    lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp (this) {

    }
    override lazy val desiredName = "xbarTestHarness"

}

object AxiMain extends App {
    println("Generating Hardware")
    implicit val p = Parameters.empty
    val verilog = (new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(LazyModule(new xbarTestHarness()).module)
}
```

and I run `sbt run`, the error is:

```
[info] running empty.AxiMain 
Generating Hardware
Exception in thread "sbt-bg-threads-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at empty.axi4Driver.<init>(crossbar.scala:80)
    at empty.xbarTestHarness.$anonfun$drivers$1(crossbar.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.generic.GenTraversableFactory.fill(GenTraversableFactory.scala:92)
    at empty.xbarTestHarness.<init>(crossbar.scala:105)
    at empty.AxiMain$.$anonfun$verilog$1(crossbar.scala:129)
    at chisel3.Module$.do_apply(Module.scala:53)
    at chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate.$anonfun$transform$2(Elaborate.scala:35)
    at chisel3.internal.Builder$.$anonfun$build$1(Builder.scala:771)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at chisel3.internal.Builder$.build(Builder.scala:766)
    at chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate.$anonfun$transform$1(Elaborate.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:290)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate.transform(Elaborate.scala:28)
    at chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate.transform(Elaborate.scala:21)
    at firrtl.options.phases.DeletedWrapper.internalTransform(DeletedWrapper.scala:38)
    at firrtl.options.phases.DeletedWrapper.internalTransform(DeletedWrapper.scala:15)
    at firrtl.options.Translator.transform(Phase.scala:248)
    at firrtl.options.Translator.transform$(Phase.scala:248)
    at firrtl.options.phases.DeletedWrapper.transform(DeletedWrapper.scala:15)
    at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.$anonfun$transform$5(DependencyManager.scala:280)
    at firrtl.Utils$.time(Utils.scala:181)
    at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.$anonfun$transform$3(DependencyManager.scala:280)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.transform(DependencyManager.scala:269)
    at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.transform$(DependencyManager.scala:255)
    at firrtl.options.PhaseManager.transform(DependencyManager.scala:443)
    at chisel3.stage.ChiselStage.run(ChiselStage.scala:45)
    at firrtl.options.Stage$$anon$1.transform(Stage.scala:43)
    at firrtl.options.Stage$$anon$1.transform(Stage.scala:43)
    at firrtl.options.phases.DeletedWrapper.internalTransform(DeletedWrapper.scala:38)
    at firrtl.options.phases.DeletedWrapper.internalTransform(DeletedWrapper.scala:15)
    at firrtl.options.Translator.transform(Phase.scala:248)
    at firrtl.options.Translator.transform$(Phase.scala:248)
    at firrtl.options.phases.DeletedWrapper.transform(DeletedWrapper.scala:15)
    at firrtl.options.Stage.$anonfun$transform$5(Stage.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at firrtl.options.Stage.$anonfun$transform$3(Stage.scala:47)
    at logger.Logger$.$anonfun$makeScope$2(Logger.scala:137)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:135)
    at firrtl.options.Stage.transform(Stage.scala:47)
    at firrtl.options.Stage.execute(Stage.scala:58)
    at chisel3.stage.ChiselStage.emitVerilog(ChiselStage.scala:101)
    at empty.AxiMain$.delayedEndpoint$empty$AxiMain$1(crossbar.scala:129)
    at empty.AxiMain$delayedInit$body.apply(crossbar.scala:123)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at empty.AxiMain$.main(crossbar.scala:123)
    at empty.AxiMain.main(crossbar.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:143)
    at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:93)
    at sbt.Run.$anonfun$runWithLoader$5(Run.scala:120)
    at sbt.Run$.executeSuccess(Run.scala:186)
    at sbt.Run.runWithLoader(Run.scala:120)
    at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$6(Defaults.scala:1980)
    at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$termWrapper$2(Defaults.scala:1919)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:369)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:268)
    at freechips.rocketchip.amba.axi4.AXI4SlaveParameters.$anonfun$new$1(Parameters.scala:23)
    at freechips.rocketchip.amba.axi4.AXI4SlaveParameters.$anonfun$new$1$adapted(Parameters.scala:23)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at freechips.rocketchip.amba.axi4.AXI4SlaveParameters.<init>(Parameters.scala:23)
    at empty.myAxiUtil$.<init>(crossbar.scala:60)
    at empty.myAxiUtil$.<clinit>(crossbar.scala)
    ... 81 more
```

I can not find out the reason leading the error. Maybe the imp of driver and accept must not be empty?

However, if I want to use the rocketchip library to generate the axicrossbar verilog module with some custom paramters(such as addrWidh, dataWidth), is there any other solution?

Comment: The real issue is in the `Caused by` stack trace, namely `at freechips.rocketchip.amba.axi4.AXI4SlaveParameters.$anonfun$new$1(Parameters.scala:23)`. I don't know what's at that line but there is a `require` that you are violating. That `require` really ought to have a message to tell you what is wrong--but in any case, that's where you should look. I think rocket-chip has multiple `Parameters.scala` files, but look for the one that contains the class definition of `AXI4SlaveParameters` since the issue is in its constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I have found that therer is an parameters error for AXI4SlaveParameters, the second argument of AddressSet() must also be a BigInt which is end with "L"